# how to pass a list of ids to screen flow via pageReference url

Tags: apex, visualforce, visual-workflow, screen-flow

1 - I have a visual force page that redirect to a screen flow using PageReference.

2 - The screen flow has a collection of text variables called ids that is allowed to receive input.

I can redirect to the screen flow from the apex code without problems, but when I pass the ids as query paramenter to the screen flow, it only gets the first id.

Is there any way to pass the full collection of ids to the flow via PageReference?

ps: I can't change the flow to receive only a string and split there.

```
public with sharing class RedirectControllerExtension {
  private List<FulfillmentOrder> records;

  public RedirectControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController) {
    records = (List<FulfillmentOrder>) standardController.getSelected();
  }

  public PageReference redirect() {
    String urlParams = '?ids=' + String.join(getFulfillmentOrdersId(records), '&ids=');
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/flow/test' + urlParams);
    return pageRef;
  }

  private List<String> getFulfillmentOrdersId(List<FulfillmentOrder> records) {
    List<String> ids = new List<String>();

    for (FulfillmentOrder record : records) {
      ids.add(record.Id);
    }

    return ids;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your Apex code with this Line
Your Code

```
String urlParams = '?ids=' + String.join(getFulfillmentOrdersId(records), '&ids=');
```

New Code(Need to be Replaced)

```
String urlParams = '?ids=' + String.join(getFulfillmentOrdersId(records), ',');
```

Also, make sure you are using a correct Flow Variable(Case Sensitive).

Comment: PS: I can't change the flow to receive only a string and split there.

I already tried you answer, it does not work because when the parameters get in the flow, it is just a string of ids separated by commas...